# Hadoop: How can i merge reducer outputs to a single file?

Tags: java, hadoop, merge, mapreduce, hdfs

I know that "getmerge" command in shell can do this work.

But what should I do if I want to merge these outputs after the job by HDFS API for java？

What i actually want is a single merged file on HDFS.

The only thing i can think of is to start an additional job after that.

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But what should I do if I want to merge these outputs after the job by HDFS API for java?

Guessing, because I haven't tried this myself, but I think the method you are looking for is [FileUtil.copyMerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.22.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String%29), which is the method that FsShell invokes when you run the `-getmerge` command.  `FileUtil.copyMerge` takes two FileSystem objects as arguments - FsShell uses FileSystem.getLocal to retrieve the destination FileSystem, but I don't see any reason you couldn't instead use Path.getFileSystem on the destination to obtain an OutputStream

That said, I don't think it wins you very much -- the merge is still happening in the local JVM; so you aren't really saving very much over `-getmerge` followed by `-put`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just tried like this: `String srcPath = "/user/hadoop/output";
String dstPath = "/user/hadoop/merged_file";
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
try {
 FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
 FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, conf, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
   
}`. That succesully merged output files as a single file on hdfs, and the order is just as my expection. But I have another question now. How does the function konw the files order ?

Comment: Here's the implementation of copyMerge:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java#FileUtil.copyMerge%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2Cboolean%2Corg.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%2Cjava.lang.String%29

It looks like it's all down to the ordering of the items returned by the FileSystem's listStatus method. I'd guess that your output files are just concatenated together.

Comment: @ Thomas, Ben :  I am trying to merge files from my reducer's output using FileUtil.copyMerge. However I have a question here, the source destination contains _SUCCESS and _log files too apart from part-r-00000. part-r-00001. Does copyMerge take in only reducer output files or should I explicitly filter what files have to me merged? If yes, how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

***You get a single Out-put File by Setting a single Reducer in your code .***

```
Job.setNumberOfReducer(1);
```

Will work for your requirement , but *costly*

---

**OR**

---

```
Static method to execute a shell command. 
Covers most of the simple cases without requiring the user to implement the Shell interface.

Parameters:
env the map of environment key=value
cmd shell command to execute.
Returns:
the output of the executed command.
```

---

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(String[])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That indeed works，but costly as you say. Is there a way to merge them by hdfs API ?

Comment: I will even go with your choice of another Job for it.
OR i have edited the ans .

Comment: yeah, may be start another job is better. I will also try execCommand before making a choice. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great answer. It's helpful if you want to prepare compressed Avro file for some external system. For example I process 5 JSON files 1Gb each and reduce output to 1 Avro file compressed with XZ to 100Mb. In other case I would get 5 Avro files 50Mb each ~ 250Mb total.